# Encrypting and Compressing a file name

Tags: java, file, encryption, file-io, hash

Say, I have a file with informations about an object. I create it with a name so that the filename itself contains certain information about the object like the object Id, object Parent Id, some other meta-id information and the file sequence number. This is done since the file is available acorss different modules and to avoid multiple database access for meta-information of file.

filename = "OB"+fileId+parentId+metaId+sequence+".txt"

sequence starts from 00001 to 99999 (could be very large also)

So, each digit at each index has a specific meaning

Now, the file information is to be made available to a program outside our application and I don't want the other applications to know the details that I use.So, i am thinking of using encryption or hashing of filename before sending the file, with a response file name within the file also encrypted or hashed, and they shall send me a response with the encrypted/hashed response filename  based on the contents of the file

There are 2 challanges :

1. the fastest and easiest way to do this without involving database
2. the filename is long about 25 characters (with other id and sequence info), so i want the resulting filename to be smaller (as small as possible) and of standard size.

Or any alternate mechanism that can be used???

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 Hash**

Using a cryptographic hash algorithm such as SHA-256 or SHA-128 will make your file names longer, and although would provide *pretty good* assurance that it's unique there's nothing guaranteeing that (all hash algorithms suffer from the Birthday paradox).

Since there's nothing guaranteeing that SHA-256 or SHA-128 will generate a file name that is unique, and depending on the level of security you need you may want to look at Adler32.  This algorithm is not going to be anywhere near as secure as the SHA family, mainly because the resulting hash size is so small you can brute force it pretty easily.  However Adler32 can provide obfuscation of the file name.

Because the resulting hash size of Alder32 is small (32 bits) the chance of collisions is much higher than the SHA family as well, therefore you will definitely need to keep some sort of table that has your file names and their corresponding hash values (and recommended in either this or the SHA case).  That table can be a simple list stored in a cache, but the main reason is that if you get a collision you will need to change your value to calculate a new hash.

**Option 2 Encryption**

Encryption will not make your data smaller, at best it will be the same size (if your data size is evenly divisible by the block size of the algorithm).  However it will retain all the data without the need to keep a table going of the encrypted values.  If you decide to go with encryption rather than a hash I would use AES for no other reason than that is the standard these days.  Encrypting the file name is such a small amount of data that you will probably not notice any difference among the algorithms, but if you are paranoid enough you can look into the AES instruction sets on the [Intel CPU's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set).

Comment: It's worth pointing out that hash functions are irreversible (except, if they are good, by brute force). Meaning that the data contained in the file name would be lost unless a separate record is maintained somewhere linking the hash to the original file name.

Comment: You are correct, however assuming that the hash is of the original file name with no alterations, having that file name on your end would be enough to re-generate the hashed value.  The reason we would still need the separate record is if there were a collision you need some mechanism to differentiate between one record and the next.  But theoretically the chance of a collision with a larger hash algorithm such as SHA-256 or SHA-128 is extremely small.